# What are the significant memory management models aside from Java (GC) and C++ (manual approach)?

Tags: java, c++, garbage-collection

There are at least two distinct memory management models:
Java (we do it for you)
C++ (it is your responsibility)

I have two questions:
(1) Is GC language specific or compiler specific?
(2) Do most languages fall in one of these two categories? Are there other memory models in commonly used languages?

---

The names of the language and corresponding memory management model would answer this question.

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article on garbage collection? Why not?

Comment: (1)  Yes.  (2) Yes.

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. Garbage collection is entirely in the first camp ("we do it for your"), if memory is managed manually then it's not GC.

Comment: I read Wiki. It doesn't have an answer to my question. I didn't know that I should prefer Wiki over peer reviewed Programmers.SE.

Comment: That's ... not really what this is about.  When you go to a professional programming website, the participants expect you to already know some fundamentals about what you are asking.  Consequently they expect you to have already done some basic research before asking your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ doesn't have a manual approach to memory management at all. If you're calling `free` in C++, you're using it wrong. That's the C way that we're proud to be disowning.

Really, the predominant models are non-deterministic (GC), deterministic (C++, D), and manual (C).

Comment: Meh.  Safe pointers are just window dressing for bare pointers, that someone only had to write once.  Garbage collection is merely a different form of window dressing, except that it's actually a first-class language construct.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, "Don't be too proud of this technological terror you've created..."

Comment: Two things to look at, I'm not familiar enough with either to fin give a full answer, but maybe others will.  First, Apple's Objective-C and Swift use automatic reference counting (ARC).  Second, the new Rust programing language uses a rich model of bindings and borrowing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The whole problem with manual memory management is the duplication. If you only had to do it once for all usages in all programs (e.g. unique_ptr) it would be totally fine.

Comment: @ErikEidt - Indeed, Rust provides the deterministic memory management as DeadMG described it but as a first-class construct like Robert Harvey appears to want it to be.